# Width toggle animation - glitchy effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a sliding effect on the text next to the image by using `animate` and `width: toggle` once a user clicks on the image (as shown in the jsfiddle below).

The problem I'm encountering is that when it's 'sliding', it glitches between words; my assumption is that it's due to words being moved around in the element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dy71s85/1/).

```js
$('img').on('click', function(e) {
  $('span').animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  }, 400)
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
<span>Name Surname</span>
```

Is there a way to fix the glitchy effect?

Comment: Please share related screenshot,  how u want to display..?

Comment: It's shown in the jsfiddle, the only issue with it, is it seems to 'glitch' or another word is not a smooth transition, as you can see once you click on the image, it gets the glitch effect between words.

Comment: @belthazorNv look at my answer.. I don't know if you can implement that way..

Comment: Please check my pure css solution

Comment: @belthazorNv  the answer of ArunSharma is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is by preventing text wrap by setting `white-space: nowrap` in your CSS code.

```js
$('img').on('click', function(e) {
  $('span').animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  }, 1200)
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
<span>Name Surname</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```js
$('img').on('click', function(e) {
 $('span').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 400);
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
<span>Name&nbsp;Surname</span>
```

Here is the Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dy71s85/6/).

Comment: nice, any explanation for this ?

Comment: @A.T. I just change the space with nbsp; thats all.. hahaha

Comment: There can be a simple css solution without touching html code as explained in my answer

Comment: @Shadow Fiend Thanks for the appreciation.